# SQL query to linq to SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I have the following query in SQL :

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM sessions
ORDER BY start_time
```

How should I code it instead in LINQ-to-SQL

Comment: It is very nice downpoint and go

Comment: I thought this is the place for some information Sharing ..

Comment: It is, but it's reasonable to expect that you might have just Googled the answer to this very basic question before asking here. It's been answered a million times before, here (I'm sure) and elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `OrderBy` for the ordering, and [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348657.aspx) or possibly [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301896.aspx) for the equivalent of `TOP 1`:

```
var session = db.Sessions.OrderBy(x => x.StartTime).FirstOrDefault();
if (session != null)
{
    // Use the session
}
else
{
    // There weren't any sessions
}
```

You *could* use a query expression for the first part, but it seems pretty pointless - it would end up being *more* long-winded than using "dot notation", so I'd stick to that.

Answer (score 3):

```
(from i in dc.sessions
orderby i.start_time).Take(1);
```

or

```
dc.sessions.OrderBy(x => x.start_time).Take(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here's an example](http://forums.asp.net/t/1203694.aspx/1):

```
NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext();

var shippers = from shipper in db.Shippers
                       orderby shipper.CompanyName
                       select shipper;

return shippers.First();
```

However, using the syntax recommended by Jon Skeet above is probably most appropriate for your simple use case.

Comment: Why bother using a query expression when all you want is an `OrderBy` call? Use query expressions when they make it *clearer*.

Comment: OP asked for a LINQ expression - that's what I delivered. I personally agree with you, prefer and most often use the lambda syntax.

Comment: The OP wrote: "How should I code it wrote it in linq" - that doesn't necessarily mean a query expression. Using the dot notation is still using LINQ.